# Adding plugin.jar to the build path in eclipse in a machine indepenent way

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working on a project that uses JSObject from the jre's plugin.jar, which isn't included in the build path normally.  I can get things to compile fine by adding the jar to the classpath.  Currently I'm doing this in eclipse via Project->Configure Build Path->Libraries->Add External JARs... -> find the jar in jdk/jre/lib/plugin.jar.  This results in a machine specific path in my .classpath file (like C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_16/jre/lib/plugin.jar).  Checking this into our repository obviously breaks the build for developers with different Java install paths or non-windows operating systems.  Is there a way to add jars from the system library using relative paths?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the "right way", but I solve this by creating a named "user" library, like "LIVE_CONNECT", whose sole content is the plugin.jar. Each developer will still have to configure their own workspace to have such a user library, but at least it will kind of document itself!

Comment: Do you need to package plugin.jar with applet.jar when you actually deploy it?

Comment: @Bostone No, you do not. It is already available on the browser's Java plugin. (Answer left for reference)